INSERT operations are not supported by requested SQL engine [native], consider using MSQ and avatica jdbc jar . #Druid #apache-druid
Issue : 2024-05-16T08:03:08,345 ERROR [qtp475172655-138] org.apache.druid.sql.avatica.DruidMeta - INSERT operations are not supported by requested SQL engine [native], consider using MSQ.
org.apache.druid.error.DruidException: INSERT operations are not supported by requested SQL engine [native], consider using MSQ.
Avatica JDBC jar : 1.25.0
url = "jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http://54.210.239.246:8888/druid/v2/sql/avatica/;transparent_reconnection=true"
common.runtime.properties contains the entry - druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-hdfs-storage", "druid-kafka-indexing-service", "druid-datasketches", "druid-multi-stage-query"]
Druid started with auto mode :
[Thu May 16 07:10:17 2024] Running command[broker]: bin/run-druid broker /home/ec2-user/apache-druid-29.0.1/conf/druid/auto '-Xms1849m -Xmx1849m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1232m'
[Thu May 16 07:10:17 2024] Running command[historical]: bin/run-druid historical /home/ec2-user/apache-druid-29.0.1/conf/druid/auto '-Xms2144m -Xmx2144m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=3216m'
[Thu May 16 07:10:17 2024] Running command[middleManager]: bin/run-druid middleManager /home/ec2-user/apache-druid-29.0.1/conf/druid/auto '-Xms67m -Xmx67m' '-Ddruid.worker.capacity=2 -Ddruid.indexer.runner.javaOptsArray=["-server","-Duser.timezone=UTC","-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8","-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError","-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager","-Xms502m","-Xmx502m","-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=502m"]'
[Thu May 16 07:10:17 2024] Running command[router]: bin/run-druid router /home/ec2-user/apache-druid-29.0.1/conf/druid/auto '-Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128m'
[Thu May 16 07:10:17 2024] Running command[coordinator-overlord]: bin/run-druid coordinator-overlord /home/ec2-user/apache-druid-29.0.1/conf/druid/auto '-Xms2010m -Xmx2010m'

I believe this issue is likely because you sent a SQL INSERT statement to the interactive query (SELECT) API.
The interactive query API is synchronous, and supports SELECT.
Asynchronous operations, including ingestion and queries that you do not need to run interactively, go to the MSQ-enabled SQL-based ingestion API.
See the SQL-based ingestion API documentation for more information.
